# Partial Least Square vs Principle Component Regression

Tags: pca, partial-least-squares

Is it the case where PLS, when compared to PCR with all things equal, generally gives lower bias but higher variance when regressed against a response Y, since PLS relates to/makes use of Y but PCR doesn't?